# Sort across two different groups and maintain object constancy

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on an interactive that admittedly isn't a typical use for D3, but it's been super helpful creating and animating the first 3 phases of a 4-part narrative. In the final stage, I'd like the user to be able to choose between several factors to sort by. In each case the sort would result in each `<rect>` being in one of two groups. In essence, this is just a grouped bar chart.

Pictures are better than words I think, so here's 2 examples: http://thatmichael.com/sandbox/immigration/sample.png

The trouble is that little gap between the 2 groups.

If all the `<rect>`s were inside the same `<g>`, I think it would be easy with something like this:

```
d3.select("#theGroup").selectAll("rect")
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return d3.ascending(a.party, b.party) || d3.ascending(a.lastName, b.lastName);
  });
```

But I would love to keep the space between the groups because it really helps to see the division.

Another sub-optimal solution is nest the data in all the possible ways, then remove and redraw all the `<rect>`s with new datasets. Something like this:

```
oldSenateByVote = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.vote;})
    .sortKeys(d3.descending)
    .entries(oldSenate);

var svg = d3.select("#barWrapper svg")
    .attr("width", bar.w)
    .attr("height", bar.h);

    var g = svg.selectAll("g.groups")
    .data(oldSenateByVote)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "groups");

    g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {return d.values})
    .enter().append("rect")
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (token.w + 1) + bar.paddingLeft;
    });
    .attr("y", bar.paddingTop)
    .attr("width", token.w)
    .attr("height", token.h)
    .each(function(d, i) {
        if (d.party == "R") {
            d3.select(this).attr("class", "token gop");
        } else {
            d3.select(this).attr("class", "token dem");
        }
    });
```

But since there's never any elements entering or exiting, it would be best if the objects remained constant.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Or maybe at least fake it? Maybe the answer is to just add a class to all of the `<rect>`s in one "group" and use that to manually move that group over 10px, though that seems really hack-ish.

Comment: Have you read the tutorial on [Object Constancy](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/)? The short answer is you need to specify a key function as the second argument to selection.data, using a unique id for each senator (firstName + lastName might work, but isn’t always unique).

Comment: A very delayed thanks for the help, Mike. D3 is such an awesome tool, and I really appreciate the time you spend answering newbie questions. Finished project is here: [http://media.cq.com/pub/2013/immigration-vote/](http://media.cq.com/pub/2013/immigration-vote/)